# How do I change the nav drawer text style when using the Android Project Template?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, navigation-drawer

I have one app where I used the tutorial here: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

I'm now working on a new project where I selected the Navigation Drawer Activity template:

[image]

Unfortunately this template works quite differently from the tutorial and I'm struggling to make changes to get it how I want it.

The nav drawer layout looks like this:

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#cccc"
android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
android:dividerHeight="0dp"
tools:context="com.example.appname.NavigationDrawerFragment" />
```

In the MainActivity in the tutorial you can set the drawer_list_item in the mDrawerList adapter:

```
mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

// Set the adapter for the list view
mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
// Set the list's click listener
mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
```

In the template things are done differently:

```
mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
mTitle = getTitle();

// Set up the drawer.
mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(R.id.navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
```

I tried manually creating a reference to the nav drawer layout and setting an adaptor but all that happened was my titles went blank.

Has anyone managed to do this successfully? Damn Google for making a template that works completely differently to their tutorial!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the answer, I was obviously not looking properly yesterday.

The set up of the nav drawer is now done in the nav drawer fragment class:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ///yada yada yada

    mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActionBar()
            .getThemedContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            android.R.id.text1, new String[] {
                    getString(R.string.title_section1),
                    getString(R.string.title_section2),
                    getString(R.string.title_section3),}));
    mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);
    return mDrawerListView;
}
```

So I simply had to change my layout resource in the ArrayAdapter:

```
mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActionBar()
            .getThemedContext(), R.layout.drawer_list_item,
            android.R.id.text1, new String[] {
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, here is a simple example on github:
Added in the navigation drawer Adapter for row Icon,name,number

https://github.com/ManolescuSebastian/Android-Mail-App/tree/master/app/src/main/java/ro/softwareinclude/android_mail_app/adapter

The usefull code that you need:

The NavigationDrawerFragment:

```
 //Pop navigation drawer item list
 List<InstantMailNavigationItem> navigationDrawerMapElementsList = new ArrayList<InstantMailNavigationItem>();
 String [] navigationItemNameArray= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.instantNavigationItemName);
 TypedArray images = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.instantNavigationItemIcon);
 for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    InstantMailNavigationItem instantMailNavigationItems = new InstantMailNavigationItem();
    instantMailNavigationItems.setItemName(navigationItemNameArray[i]);
    instantMailNavigationItems.setItemImageResource(getResources().getDrawable(images.getResourceId(i,-1)));
    navigationDrawerMapElementsList.add(instantMailNavigationItems);
   }
    NavigatorAdapter navigatorAdapter = new NavigatorAdapter(getActionBar().getThemedContext(), navigationDrawerMapElementsList);
    mDrawerListView.setAdapter(navigatorAdapter);
```

The Adapter class:

```
public class NavigatorAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

 private Context context;
 private ViewHolder holder;
 private List<InstantMailNavigationItem> navigationDrawerElements;
 public NavigatorAdapter(Context context, List<InstantMailNavigationItem>  instantMailNavigationItems) {
 super(context, R.layout.navigator_adapter,instantMailNavigationItems);
 this.context = context;
 this.navigationDrawerElements = instantMailNavigationItems;
}

 /**
 * getView method is called for each item of ListView
 */
 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     InstantMailNavigationItem navigationItem = navigationDrawerElements.get(position);
     LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)          context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.navigator_adapter, null);
     holder = new ViewHolder();
     init(convertView,holder);
     holder.navDrawerItemName.setText(navigationItem.getItemName());
     holder.navDrawerItemIcon.setImageDrawable(navigationItem.getItemImageResource());
     return convertView;
     }

     public void init(View convertView, ViewHolder holder) {
     holder.navDrawerItemIcon = (ImageView)    convertView.findViewById(R.id.navDrawerItemIcon);
     holder.navDrawerItemName = (TextView)        convertView.findViewById(R.id.navDrawerItemName);
     holder.navDrawerItemNumber = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.navDrawerItemNumber);
     }

    static class ViewHolder{
      ImageView navDrawerItemIcon;
      TextView navDrawerItemName;
      TextView navDrawerItemNumber;
    }
  }
```

Comment: I appreciate the efforts but I can't really see how I can apply that without having to redo a lot of my code. It would be easier to just revert back to the code in their tutorial.